# Inhibit input's onchange when jQuery UI Autocomplete is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a text input element that uses jQuery UI Autocomplete.  The input has an `onchange` event bound to it to change some other form values based on the user's selection.  I also want to change those other form values when the user selects an option from the autocomplete.

The problem is that if a user is looking up "beer", but only types "bee" and then clicks on the beer option in the autocomplete, the input's `onchange` fires with a value of "bee", and then the autocomplete's select function fires (with the correct value of "beer").  Since both of these handlers utilize an ajax call to lookup some stuff, I get into a race condition.

My question is: Is there some way that I can have the `onchange` either not fire, or abort, in the case where a user clicked on an autocomplete option.  Note: this only happens when clicking, selecting an option using only the keyboard does not fire the input's `onchange`.

It's not an option for me to just disable the `onchange` entirely when the autocomplete is active, since it's believable that the user will just keep typing, and exit out of the input without selecting anything from the autocomplete.

I've done a fair bit of `console.log()`'ing, and the `onchange` event fires before all other events I can think of, including the input's `focusout`, the autocomplete's item's focus, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is precisely the reason for autocomplete's [`change`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-change) event. It sounds like you should be able to leverage this event to perform logic based on whether or not the user selected an item (thereby removing your `onchange` and `autocompleteselect` event handlers). For example:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: ['hi', 'bye', 'foo', 'bar'],
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            /* user selected an item */           
        } else {
            /* user entered a new item */
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bdDs7/

Comment: Andrew - Thank you very much. This use of the change method is exactly what I need.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker any thoughts about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/20513604/829533